# java this type of comment type unknown

Tags: java

There are 3 types of comments in java.

- Single Line Comment : `//just like this`
- Multi Line Comment : `starts with /* and ends with */`
- Documentation Comment : `starts with /** and ends with */`

Then what is this type of comment called :

```
/*
* this 
* works
* as
* comment 
* too
* */
```

Comment: Doesn't start with `//` so not Single-line; doesn't start with `/**`, so not JavaDoc; does start with `/*` and end with `*/`, therefore, just a basic "Multi-line" comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your comment starts with `/*` and ends with `*/` it is a *multi line* comment.